# How to tar a directory preserving not only permissions, but ownership too

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, tar, ownership

I have to compress a directory using tar.gz preserving not only permissions, but ownership/groups too.

And, in this directory there are many files that belong to many users.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The owners of the file is preserved by default.

When extracting you need to use `--same-owner` flag. Such as `tar --same-owner -xvf file.tar` although the flag is only recommended for super users.

Check the [tar man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Comment: It has to be `tar -cvpf file.tar` (or perhaps better yet in terms of clarity, `-cvp -f file.tar`). Otherwise the `-fp` part is interpreted as `--file p`, and `tar` is writing to the file named `p` instead of `file.tar`.

Comment: Also, given that the answer mentioned compression and people tend to copy-paste answers from posts without thinking anyway, let me note that the popular archiving idiom with compression would be: `tar -czvpf file.tar.gz folderToCompress` or `tar -cjvpf file.tar.bz2 folderToCompress`.

Comment: @KT - you are correct, so I fix the `-f` flag -- although I didn't fix the compression `-z` flag.  For compression, I'd recommend `-Ipigz` (that's a capital i)  in lieu of `-z`; on multi-core systems, pigz can be considerably faster.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `p` is an **extraction** flag, it will have no effect at archive creation. It also affects file permissions, not ownership. The respective flag for ownership is `--same-owner`, which is enabled by default when extracting as `root`.

Comment: @NVRAM SnowRep *undid* your changes (!!!). SnowRep, I'm downvoting you and restoring NVRAM's edit, which is **correct**. Please do not intentionally put incorrect info on the site!

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev , you are right. If you ant, you can post a new answer and I'll set it as accepted.

Comment: To extract with `--same-owner` you need to be root. And `--same-owner` also affects the `t` command. And about `-fp` being interpreted as `--file p`, in [traditional style](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/tar/tar.1.en#Option_styles) you first specify options (single letters), then arguments. So `tar cvfp file.tar...` would make it create `file.tar`, not `p`.

Comment: On the subject of things directly after `-f` being interpreted as the file, I believe that's a GNU tar specific thing, the POSIX tar (BusyBox for example) doesn't do that. Still, unless you are sure which one you are using, I'd recommend using `f` as the last option before the file name (thanks GNU :P)

Answer (score 56):

> I have to compress a directory using tar.gz preserving not only permissions, but ownership/groups too.

By default, `tar` will preserve file permissions and ownership when *creating* the archive.

To extract file permissions and ownership, you will need to run `tar` as root when extracting, since changing file ownership usually requires superuser privileges. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463325/what-does-tars-p-preserve-permissions-flag-actually-preserve) for more information.

Comment: When you say it preserves ownership, does that mean both the user and the group?

Comment: That's correct. Both the owner and group are recorded by default (at least in GNU tar).