# Mac OS terminal command

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal

I am using Mac OS 10.13.2 terminal to create a 'tar' copy of a folder and would like to know as to how I can preserve the owner and group when creating the backup. Also, when extracting the folder have the same owner and group for the extracted folder as the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tar a directory preserving not only permissions, but ownership too](https://superuser.com/questions/838392/how-to-tar-a-directory-preserving-not-only-permissions-but-ownership-too)

Comment: `tar` already saves all that information. It does not restore it by default, though.